# Significato di "capire il macinato"

Tags: word-usage, meaning, regional, idioms

Nel racconto *Arsenico* dal libro *Il sistema periodico*, di Primo Levi, ho letto (grassetto mio):

> Lui mi voleva male a me, e diceva in giro un mucchio di bugiarderie. Che risuolo col cartone. Che mi ubriaco tutte le sere. Che ho fatto morire mia moglie per l’assicurazione. Che a un mio cliente è spuntato un chiodo dalla suola e poi è morto di tetano. E allora, con le cose a questo punto, capisce che non mi sono stupito mica tanto quando un mattino, in mezzo alle scarpe della giornata, ho trovato questo cartoccio. **Ho subito capito il macinato**, ma volevo essere sicuro: cosí ne ho dato un poco al gatto, e dopo due ore è andato in un angolo e ha vomitato.

Il passaggio fa riferimento a un pacco di zucchero che un anziano ciabattino aveva chiesto all'autore di analizzare:

> In ottimo piemontese dunque, con argute venature astigiane, mi disse che aveva dello zucchero da chimicare: voleva sapere se era zucchero o no, o se c’era magari dentro qualche porcheria («saloparía»).

Anche questo "chimicare" è curioso, ma si capisce e
se ne parla sul [sito web dell'Associazione culturale Chimicare](http://www.chimicare.org/sul-termine-chimicare/): sembra trattarsi di un verbo di uso popolare nel passato col significato di "analizzare chimicamente".

Nel brano che ho citato prima, questo ciabattino   spiega all'autore come gli è arrivato questo pacco una volta è già stato analizzato nel piccolo laboratorio gestito da Levi e un suo amico e si è scoperto che conteneva arsenico.  Gli parla anche di un giovane calzolaio che ha aperto una
bottega vicino alla sua e agisce nel modo indicato nel passo.

Ho cercato alla voce "macinato" di parecchi dizionari, ma non ho trovato l'espressione "capire il macinato" e sul dizionario dei modi di dire Hoepli non esiste questo lemma. Cosa vuol dire? Dal contesto, sembrerebbe qualcosa come "capire cosa stava succedendo", ma non ne sono sicura. Si tratta di qualche sorta di modo di dire, magari di uso locale?

**Aggiornamento:**

Nei commenti alla domanda si è suggerito che "macinato" potrebbe essere lo zucchero o quello che ci fosse nel cartoccio  (il calzolaio pensa che sia zucchero, ma non ne è sicuro) e, allora, "capire il macinato" significherebbe capire che cos'è o che cosa c'è dentro al "macinato". Tuttavia,
veramente il calzolaio non capisce subito che
cos'è o che cosa c'è dentro  alla sostanza che si trova nel cartoccio: pensa sia zucchero, ma non ne è sicuro; ha il sospetto che ci sia anche "qualche porcheria", ma non sa cos'è e, per questa ragione, lo porta ad analizzare in laboratorio. Forse il significato è intuire che cos'è o sospettare che cos'è (zucchero mescolato a "qualche porcheria")?

Comment: "Chimicare" è una sorta di "neologismo" per indicare "analizzare chimicamente"; secondo me qui "capire il macinato" ha un significato simile, di "analizzare il macinato" (Capire = Comprendere con l’intelletto)

Comment: @RiccardoDeContardi: Cioè, vorrebbe dire "analizzare lo zucchero"? "Il macinato" può voler dire "lo zucchero"? Tuttavia, non è il calzolaio ad analizzare lo zucchero: lo porta al piccolo laboratorio gestito da Levi e un suo amico per essere analizzato.

Comment: C'è un sito web chiamato [chimicare.org](http://www.chimicare.org/) che cita appunto questo passo di Primo Levi.

Comment: Ah! Questo stesso sito web [spiega l'uso del termine "chimicare"](http://www.chimicare.org/sul-termine-chimicare/): non sembra trattarsi di un neologismo, ma di un verbo di uso popolare nel passato.

Comment: Sì, ho usato il termine neologismo per indicare una parola diciamo "inventata"...

Comment: Il macinato è qualunque sostanza che sia stata appunto macinata. Nell'uso contemporaneo fa pensare soprattutto alla carne; storicamente, soprattutto alla farina (fu famosa la “tassa sul macinato” in questo senso, che adesso fa un po' sorridere perché fa pensare alle polpette). Dal contesto potrebbe essere che qui lo riferisca allo zucchero (anche se tecnicamente dovrebbe essere “semolato”). Qualunque cosa sia, interpreto quell'espressione come “ho capito subito che cos'era/che cosa c'era dentro al macinato, ma etc.”

Comment: @DaG:  Sì, era zucchero, ma sembra che il calzolaio ne avesse qualche dubbio perché il testo dice "mi disse che aveva dello zucchero da chimicare: voleva sapere se era zucchero o no, [...]". Può darsi che il significato sia questo, ma veramente il calzolaio non capisce subito che cos'è o che cosa c'è dentro al "macinato": pensa sia zucchero, ma non ne è sicuro; ha il sospetto che ci sia anche "qualche porcheria", ma non sa cos'è e, per questa ragione, lo porta ad analizzare in laboratorio.

Comment: Ah! Ho risposto alla prima versione del commento, @DaG. (Se "il macinato" può essere lo zucchero, non so se dovrei modificare la domanda: io non avevo capito "il macinato" :).

Comment: La mia impressione è che Levi volesse intendere “il risultato della macchinazione” (l'assonanza è casuale): immagina il suo avversario che fa progetti per danneggiarlo e li macina nella mente e nell'azione.

Comment: "Capire il macinato" significa "capire la situazione", vedere la sostanza o realtà della cosa, un po' come "mangiare la foglia"; è una frase idiomatica che ha nulla a che vedere con il contenuto del cartoccio.

Comment: Non mi era venuto in mente di ricercare nel libro di Villata fino a quando non ho letto il contenuto del link che appare nella risposta di linuxfan, che afferma si tratta di un piemontesismo.  Come altre espressioni di origine piemontese presenti nel *Sistema periodico* ("tirare l'ala", "attaccare secco", "dare la larga") si trova qui: https://books.google.es/books?id=1sNUDwAAQBAJ&pg=PR49&lpg=PR49&dq=%22tirare+l%27ala%22&source=bl&ots=f9liAUv8iZ&sig=ACfU3U1SRGh7Y89b5wvhqaj9ZQ9pAt92uQ&hl=it&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiqm5jFqY7qAhWKHhQKHQQuAB0Q6AEwBnoECAgQAQ#v=onepage&q=macinato&f=false.

Comment: A quanto pare, non sono stata l'unica a "non capire il macinato", @DaG ;).

Answer (score 2):

Si trova una spiegazione di questa espressione nel libro [*Primo Levi e il piemontese. La lingua de «La chiave a stella»*](https://books.google.es/books?id=1sNUDwAAQBAJ&pg=PR49&lpg=PR49&dq=%22tirare+l%27ala%22&source=bl&ots=f9liAUv8iZ&sig=ACfU3U1SRGh7Y89b5wvhqaj9ZQ9pAt92uQ&hl=it&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiqm5jFqY7qAhWKHhQKHQQuAB0Q6AEwBnoECAgQAQ#v=onepage&q=macinato&f=false), di [Bruno Villata](https://www.concordia.ca/artsci/cmll/faculty.html?fpid=bruno-villata),  in cui si fa un'analisi del linguaggio di un altro dei romanzi di Primo Levi.

Una delle sue sezioni fa un elenco di quello che l'autore chiama "calchi semantici", cioè,

> lemmi riportati dai dizionari italiani, ma che ne *La chiave a stella* sono associati a significati diversi da quelli segnalati per la lingua italiana o che comunque sono di gran uso in piemontese e non in italiano

Tra questi si trova appunto "macinato":

> **MACINATO** 
> Che i dizionari italiani definiscono come "pp. di macinare/sm. ogni biada e sim. che sia già macinata. Tassa sul macinato =
> farina" (Palazzi 1970, p. 660). Però l'espressione piemontese
> **capì el macinato** equivale a "capire il trucco, capire come vanno le cose" (Palazzi 1970, p. 660; Gribaudo 1983, p. 484):
> "alla fine si è capito il macinato", p. 23.

Dunque, l'espressione nel testo farebbe riferimento al fatto che il ciabattino anziano aveva subito capito il trucco, aveva compreso come stavano le cose: se n'era accorto che quel pacco rappresentava un imbroglio teso dal calzolaio giovane.

Da notare che la domanda menziona che questo ciabattino si esprimeva "in ottimo piemontese". Quindi, mi sembra naturale che, sebbene il testo sia in italiano, Levi metta in bocca di questo personaggio un'espressione che ha come origine un calco dal piemontese.

Comment: La fonte, il professore [Bruno Villata](https://www.concordia.ca/artsci/cmll/faculty.html?fpid=bruno-villata), tra i cui temi di ricerca si trova "Romance Philology;  Italian Dialectology; ancient and moderm Piedmontese", e che ha scritto parecchi libri sulla lingua piemontese, mi sembra autorevole.

Comment: E poi, anche l'articolo di Beccaria trovato da @linuxfan lo dà come piemontesismo ("piemontesismo" significa che l'origine del modo di dire è la lingua piemontese: l'uso che se ne fa oggi potrebbe essere più esteso: questo veramente non lo so, ma i commenti alla domanda sembrano indicare che non è usato in tutta Italia).

Answer (score 1):

> Capire il macinato

Comprendere la situazione.

Una ricerca su google di "capire il macinato" riporta alcuni risultati:

[proverbi piemontesi, al #27](https://pms.wikisource.org/wiki/Proverbi_piemont%C3%A8is/c). In realtà non si tratta di un proverbio ma di un modo di dire: il macinato è quello che esce (per esempio) da una macina, l'essenza destrutturata,  spogliata dell'inutile (come l'aspetto), e riassemblata, di ciò che era stato introdotto.

["I due mestieri" di Beccaria](https://docplayer.it/164795728-Acc-sc-torino-quaderni-32-2019-cucire-parole-cucire-molecole-i-due-mestieri-g-l-b.html) parla di Levi e accenna anche al "macinato" (disponibile anche in [PDF all'Accademia delle scienze](https://www.accademiadellescienze.it/media/1426/download)). Bel testo, molto interessante, potrebbe contenere qualche piccola e rara imprecisione. Dico "potrebbe" perché il Piemontese è vasto e non è codificato con precisione: alcune accezioni variano da zona a zona.

Comment: @Charo non è un proverbio (ho modificato la risposta), e non credo che sia "esattamente" un piemontesismo o un modo di dire regionale.

Comment: Veramente hai trovato qualche fonte che indichi che l'origine non sia piemontese? Potresti aggiungerla alla risposta, per favore? "Regionale" non significa che si usi soltanto in una regione, per cui la tag mi sembra pertinente: potrei sbagliare su questo aspetto, ma i commenti alla domanda sembrano indicare che non si tratti di un modo di dire usato in tutta Italia (questo è appunto il significato di "regionale").